# How do I make a 16 inch mac display to a 13 inch mac display?

Tags: macos, mac, macbook

I want to introduce black bars so that entire 16 inch mac display will be reduced to that of 13 inch mac. I want this to reduce eye strain.

Basically I want to introduce black bars on all four sides.

Comment: Would setting a black wallpaper and making your application windows smaller work for you?

Comment: You are making the display smaller - that will **increase** eye strain.

Comment: If you want to reduce eye strain, wouldn't zooming/enlarging the screen content be the better approach?

Comment: I just want less light to focus on my eye thats all! please don't start conversation about science just tell me if there is any way or software to do this....

Comment: I want entire display to be smaller

Comment: Have you tried changing the Display resolution resolution, it wont shrink the size on the monitor but will be easier to see.

Comment: Try changing the resolution in the display settings pane.  You need a 2560x1440 to match the resolution of the 13".  You may have to hold the `Opt` key down to get the extra settings.  I don't have a16" to test, but I doubt it will work.  According to [everymac.com](https://bit.ly/2vHA31W), your display only supports scaled resolutions of 2048x1280, 1792x1120, 1344x840, and 1152x720.  In all honesty, this is not the use case that Apple designs for.